# How to use TCharHelper?

Tags: delphi, char, delphi-xe5

The next code:

```
function get_symbol (var s: String): String;
var c: Char;
    p: Int32;
begin
// ... some more code ...
   c := upcase (s [p]);
   if IsDigit (c) then
```

causes the following error message:

`[dcc32 Warning] fmx_utilities_string.pas(188): W1000 Symbol 'IsDigit' is deprecated: 'Use TCharHelper'`

I don't understand this message as System.Character is included, c is declared to be Char and TCharhelper is declared as a character helper of Char. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're not using [TCharHelper](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Character.TCharHelper); you're using the old System.Character [IsDigit](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Character.IsDigit) function instead. The way to use `TCharHelper.IsDigit` is:

```
if c.IsDigit then
  ...
```